# How to read Custom Http Header from the response using com.sun.jersey.api?

Tags: java, httpresponse, jersey-client, response-headers

I am using `com.sun.jersey.api`.

Below is the code part to get the response Header.

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource( url );
ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Authorization", authorization )
                                     .header( "X-FeClient-Token",clienttoken)
                                     .post( ClientResponse.class, "" );

MultivaluedMap<String, String> respmap=response.getHeaders();
```

It only gives the default header details. I am not able to get the Custom Headers sent in the response.  I am able to see the custom header in the postman tool.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the headers are blocked by the provider that you are using.You need to enable them. Depending on the framework you are using you will need to implement a Filter to do that.

```
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```